# Android "Tu dispositivo no es compatible con esta version"

Tags: android, google-play

He intentado encontrar la causa por la que mi aplicación no es compatible con dispositivos con api 21 y 22, cuando la busco en la play store me muestra el siguiente mensaje

> "tu dispositivo no es compatible con esta versión",

pero esta publicada haciéndolo compatible con una api min 21.

He probado a crear emuladores con Genymotion pero el resultado siempre es el mismo.

Archivo build.gradle:

```
    buildscript {
    ext.androidSdkVersion = 30
    ext.androidMinSdkVersion = 21
    ext.androidBuildToolsVersion = '30.0.2'
    ext.hiltVersion = '2.38.1'
    ext.kotlinVersion = "1.5.31"
    ext.composeVersion = "1.0.5"

    apply from: "scripts/gradle/repositories.gradle"

    repositories {
        addRepos(repositories)
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.8.1'
        classpath 'io.michaelrocks:paranoid-gradle-plugin:0.3.2'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:perf-plugin:1.4.0'
        classpath 'org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle:4.15.2'
        classpath "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:$hiltVersion"
        classpath "gradle.plugin.com.github.konifar.gradle:plugin:0.3.3"
        classpath 'org.sonarsource.scanner.gradle:sonarqube-gradle-plugin:3.1.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlinVersion"
    }
}
```

Los permisos en el Manifest:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.fingerprint"
        android:required="false" />
```

Answer (score 0):

De acuerdo a la configuración definida en `build.gradle` tu aplicación es soportada desde dispositivos Android 5.0 (nivel de API 21) hasta los actuales:

```
ext.androidMinSdkVersion = 21
```

Si obtienes el mensaje:

> "tu dispositivo no es compatible con esta versión"

Tu dispositivo es de una versión menor a Android 5.0 o hay una caracteristica de Hardware requerida en tu aplicación que no se tiene en tu dispositivo, veo que usas la camara por lo tanto te sugiero usar `android:required="false"` , si no cuenta con esta caracteristica de hardware y no es esencial para su funcionamiento, la aplicación podrá ser soportada en tu dispositivo:

```
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="false"/>
```